# Codesign error while installing an app on the iPhone from a different Mac

Tags: ios, installation, codesign

I've published my app on the App Store. Now I want to release an update of this app, but obviously I want to test it on the device. Unfortunately my iPhone is broken, so I've sent the  Xcode project to my friend that owns a Mac and iPhone.

He installed the app on its own Mac and iPhone. At this point, if he executes the app from the iPhone simulator, everything works fine; but if he tries to install the app on its own iPhone, he receives the following error:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS 5.0'

I've tried to remove my Code Signing Identity from the Build Settings in Xcode with no result. Any ideas or suggestions please?

Comment: Not exactly your answer, but it's much easier to send your friend an 'ad-hoc' build to test for you, I do it with all my mates to beta test my stuff - easy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export your developer profile from your old Mac and import it on your new Mac.  You do this in the Xcode Organizer window.

Either that or your friend needs to generate a new set of keys/certs/mobileprovisions.